# How to handle MaxAttemptsExceededException in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

Laravel queue will throw `MaxAttemptsExceededException` when job will take a long time.
I want to handle this exception and do some stuff when this error occurs.

I tries to catch it in handle method but it did not worked.

Thanks for your help.